# Urn of balls: same marginal probability of red for all picks?

Tags: probability

(This is inspired from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949591/178464).)

Suppose we have an urn with $\color{red}{m\text{ red balls}}$ and $\color{blue}{n \text{ blue balls}}$. We pick out one ball at a time without replacement. Let $A_j$ be the probability of that the $j$-th picked ball is red. In the link above, it is shown that $\Pr(A_1)=\Pr(A_2)=\frac{m}{m+n}$. I suspect it is in fact true that 
$$
\Pr(A_1)=\cdots=\Pr(A_{m+n})=\frac{m}{m+n}. 
$$
(I've also computed $\Pr(A_3)$ and it also equals $\frac{m}{m+n}$.)

My **intuition** is as follows: imagine the balls in the urn are poured into a tube so that the balls are now stacked linearly. Then, a picking order in the urn corresponds to a permutation of balls in the tube and the picking is done by reaching into the tube from one end only and picking out the first reached ball repeatedly. Since any the balls are physically (other than color) identical, all permutations have the same probability. Thus,
$$
\Pr(A_1)=\Pr(A_2)=\cdots=\Pr(A_{m+n})=\Pr(\text{first ball from the tube is red})
$$
but the latter is $\frac{m}{m+n}$ since we're still getting one ball blindly out of a collection of $m$ reds and $n$ blues.

**Question**: is any of this correct? If so, could you please formalize the argument above (does it have a name)? If not, what are $\Pr(A_1),\ldots,\Pr(A_{m+n})$?

Comment: How did you get $ P(A_{3}) = \frac{m}{m + n} $ as the answer? 


I have $ P(A_{3}) = P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})) + P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}) = P(A_{1} \cap A_{2}).P(A_{3}|A_{1} \cap A_{2}) + P((A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}).P(A_{3}|(A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}) $

Comment: $P(A_3)=P[A_3\cap(A_1\cap A_2)]+P[A_3\cap(A_1\cap\neg A_2)]+P[A_3\cap(\neg A_1\cap A_2)]+P[A_3\cap(\neg A_1\cap\neg A_2)]$. The first term then equals $\frac{m-2}{m+n-2}\frac{m-1}{m+n-1}\frac{m}{m+n}$ and so on and so forth.

Comment: Can you explain why we need the terms $ P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2}^{C})) + P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1}^{C} \cap A_{2})) $ in calculating $ P(A_{3})? $
Since $ A_{3} = (A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})) \cup (A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}) $ and since $ (A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})) \cap (A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}) = \emptyset, $ that's how I arrive at the sum $ P(A_{3}) = P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})) + P(A_{3} \cap (A_{1} \cap A_{2})^{C}). $

Comment: Because while it's clear that $P[A_3\mid(A_1\cup A_2)]$ is, it's not easy what $P[A_3\mid\neg (A_1\cup A_2)]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

One way to formalize it is to split the drawing of the balls in two parts :

- choosing $p$ balls from the urn
- assigning each of the $p$ balls to a position between 1 and $p$

Whatever drawing occur in the first phase, there is a perfect symmetry between the roles of the $p$ positions in the second phase, and all the positions have the same probability of getting a red ball assigned. Since this equality occurs in every configuration of the first phase, the probabilities of all $A_i$ are the same.

You should look up Hypergeometric Distribution to see the formalization of these kind of dynamics, that are involved when you try to compute the distribution of successes among samples drawn without replacement.